# Node JS [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

Hi lets say I have code like this:

```
router.get('/blablabla', function(req, res, next) {
    model
      .findOne({condition : req.body.condition})
      .then(function(data) {
        if(data) {
          return res.send("data already exists");
        }
        else {
          //DO CREATE THE NEW DATA

          return modelInstance.save();
        }
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        if(data) res.send("new data successfully saved");
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

In current condition if data already exists, there will be error

```
**[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)**
```

Why this error raised? based on my knowledge after res.send() is being called then all the later code below it will not be executed right?

I am return data.save() because I want avoid nesting statement.

## UPDATE ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

```
router.get('/blablabla', function(req, res, next) {
    model
      .findOne({condition : req.body.condition})
      .then(function(data) {
        if(data) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            return resolve();
          });
        }
        else {
           //DO CREATE THE NEW DATA

          return modelInstance.save();
        }
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        if(data) res.send("new data successfully saved");
        else res.send("data already exists");
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `.then()` handler will still execute because the promise is not branched, it's chained so the chain keeps going and thus you will be doing two `res.send()` operations and that's what causes the error you see.

When you do:

```
return res.send("data already exists");
```

You are just returning a value from the `.then()` handler.  Since that value is not a rejected promise, the promise stays resolved and the next `.then()` handler in the chain will execute.

You could do this:

```
router.get('/blablabla', function (req, res, next) {
    model.findOne({condition: req.body.condition}).then(function (data) {
        if (data) {
            return res.send("data already exists");
        } else {
            //DO mMODIFY THE DATA AND THEN SAVE THE DATA
            return data.save().then(function () {
                res.send("new data successfully saved");
            });
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Or, you could do this (modification of your second try - assumes that `data.save()` returns a promise that resolves to a value):

```
router.get('/blablabla', function(req, res, next) {
    model
      .findOne({condition : req.body.condition})
      .then(function(data) {
        if (!data) {
          //DO mMODIFY THE DATA AND THEN SAVE THE DATA
          return data.save();
        }
        return data;
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        if(data) res.send("new data successfully saved");
        else res.send("data already exists");
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

Comment: >You are just returning a value from the .then() handler.

Which data I returned? and which `.then` handler?
Sorry I a little bit confuse at those.

Comment: @Kim - Read again starting with "When you do:".  That's the line of code I'm 'talking about.

Comment: If I do `data.save().then()` it will be nesting. For example: how if after `data.save().then()`, I will still do some condition check again and save the data again?

Comment: okay I got it now. But if I do like that, if the code getting much complex. It will become nesting right?

Comment: Your desire is to branch a promise, not just continue it on - that is usually done with one level of nesting.

Comment: Oh jfriend, I got some new idea and it's work. I will update the code and I need your opinion. Is it good or not?

Comment: Hey, I already updated my code. In your opinion its good or not? If its not good, I will stick with your solution

Comment: @Kim - You don't need to create a promise.  See my modification to your second try in my answer.

Comment: Wow very great, I will definitely use that. Thank you :)

Comment: @Kim - Actually, there's something wrong here.  Why are you doing `data.save()` when `data` was falsey?  That won't work.

Comment: Oh sorry jfriend. I think I made wrong example. In my real code, it will create new document. I will update it. Thank you